# How do I get a variable-input class value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Hope you are all doing well.

I'm building an 'online store' and I need to count how many items my user wants to buy. The store will have *n* forms, which have an input and a button to send the object to the shopping cart.

I'm supposed to get input for the specific button clicked, which is the how many items the user wants to buy. It should be something like `$(this).val() input`, but I'm not sure how I should write the code.

Here's the code:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card small">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="animal.jpg">
        <span class="card-title">Kesha - Animal (CD)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content animal">
        <form style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">

          <input type = "number" class = "qntd" placeholder="Quantidade" style = "width: 100%; margin-top: -20px;" maxlength="10">

          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" value = "animal">Adicionar ao saco
            <i class="material-icons right">attach_money</i>
          </button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card small">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="cannibal.jpg">
        <span class="card-title">Kesha - Cannibal (CD)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content cannibal">
        <form style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">

          <input type = "number" class = "qntd" placeholder="Quantidade" style = "width: 100%; margin-top: -20px;" maxlength="10">

          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" value = "cannibal">Adicionar ao saco
            <i class="material-icons right">attach_money</i>
          </button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  let animal = $('.animal button').val();
  let animalqntd = $('.animal .qntd').val();

  let cannibal = $('.cannibal button').val();
  let cannibalqntd = $('.cannibal .qntd').val();

  localStorage.setItem($(this).val(), $('$(this).val() input').val());
  console.log(localStorage.getItem($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: `$('$(this).val() input').val()` that's your problem ...

Comment: But putting only input will get me the first input on the page, not the one in the form that the user typed.

Comment: perhaps `$($(this).val() + ' input').val()`

Comment: unfortunately, returns undefined

Comment: well, explain how the `input` is related to the `button`

Comment: Missed the '.' for the class. $('.' + $(this).val() + ' input').val() worked! thank you!

Comment: ahhh, there you go :p